# An example for infinite dimensional vector space with Hamel dimension smaller than $\operatorname{card} F$

Tags: vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples

What will be the example for a vector space(infinite dimensional) over a field where Hamel basis has strictly smaller cardinality than that of field?

It is not possible in a Hilbert Space (over R or C)

Comment: The only cases where this is not possible is when the field is finite or countably infinite.

Comment: @egreg obviously yes there is no smaller cardinality than that of N. This is possible with CC also

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The space of $\mathbb R[X]$ of polynomials over $\mathbb R$ has a countable basis: $1, X, X^2, \dots$.

More generally, if $K$ is a field and $X$ is any set, then the space of all functions $X \to K$ having finite support is a $K$-vector space having a basis of cardinality $|X|$: a basis is given by the functions that are zero everywhere except at exactly one point of $X$. So, you only need to take $X$ an infinite set of cardinality strictly smaller than that of $K$. The example above is this one with $K=\mathbb R$ and $X=\mathbb N$. It is actually the smallest possible example.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles Since lhf specified we were looking at the set of functions $X\to K$ which were nonzero for at most finitely many $x \in X$, the indicator functions do form a basis (though they would not if we looked at the larger space of all functions from $X$ to $K$ and $X$ were infinite).

Comment: @Strants: Oops, I just missed that part it seems.

Comment: This is the smallest possible example, *provided* $\mathsf{CH}$ holds.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Continuum hypothesis has no role here. The fact that $|\mathbb{R}|>|\mathbb{N}|$ is independent of CH, nor is the fact that $|\mathbb{N}|$ is the smallest infinite cardinal.

Comment: @egreg why CH has no role here in proving it is smallest possible example. If CH fails, I'll take K to be set with cardinality between that of A and R.

Comment: @Sushil I don't get it: $K$ is a field; if it is not countable, then there exists a vector space over it with a basis of cardinality less than $|K|$. What's the role of CH?

Comment: No not in it. But when u said. "This is smallest possible example."

Answer (score 5):

Here is kind of a silly way of constructing such objects.

Let $F$ be any field, and let $X$ be any infinite set. Then we can form the free $F$-vector space $V$ on $X$, consisting of all formal sums of finitely many terms
$$V=\{\textstyle\sum \alpha_ix_i:\alpha_i\in F,\;x_i\in X\}$$
of which $X$ is an obvious basis, so that $V$ has dimension $|X|$ as an $F$-vector space.

Now let $Y$ be any infinite set of cardinality strictly larger than that of $X$, and form the field of rational functions $K=F(Y)$, so that $|K|\geq |Y|>|X|$.

Then $V\otimes_F K$ has dimension $|X|$ as a $K$-vector space, but it is now a vector space over the field $K$ with $|X|<|K|$.